# OpenCV 3.0 - How can I create a cv::Mat from CSV string?

Tags: c++, csv, opencv, opencv3.0, opencv-mat

I'm trying to create a cv::Mat from a CSV string that I pipe from a python-script. I'm currently using python 2.7, C++ and OpenCV 3.0, and all I can find is how to do it in OpenCV 2.4, but the problem is that it differs a lot from 3.0 where the ml::TrainData somehow is used instead. I don't understand how it works, and theres no example code! :-(

What my python-script does is that it pipes the np.array as CSV, it looks like this:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import csv


csvToSend = csv.writer(sys.stdout, delimiter=',')

data = np.array([ [3, 7, 9],
               [1, 7, 0],
               [4, 12, 8]])

csvToSend.writerows(data)
```

The python-script is currently simulating a camera sending picture in bgr RAW format.

The piped data is received by my C++ code, this is how the code looks for the moment:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

string values = "", csvPart;
Mat img;
int i;

int main()
{
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {

        cin >> csvPart; //here I get my CSV lines from python-script

        if (values == "") values = values + csvPart;

        else values = values + "\n" + csvPart;  //makes the CVS lines look like a 3x3 matrix again
    }

    cout << values << endl; //prints the CVS to see that it looks like it did before piping it over to the C++ code

    /* how the printed string looks like
    3,7,9 
    1,7,0
    4,12,8    */

/*      Here I want to load the "values" into the Mat img
        so I can do my mojo with openCV in C++          */
}
```

It would be much appreciated if someone could help me out with this and give me a simple code example. 
If there is a better way of piping the np.array over to the C++ code and load it into a cv::Mat my arms are open for you! ;-)

Comment: A better way would be to use FileStorage (xml or yml) to pass the matrix (but I ignore if it can be use also in Python).

Comment: If I understood it correct it would be much more time/process consuming to use xml or yml, also there is no need to save the data unless it speeds up the process. Might mention that I use a Raspberry Pi 2 to run my code on. @Miki

Comment: ...it looks like I wrote in the code comments above /*how the printed string... @Miki

Comment: Do you know rows, cols and channels? Or you should deduce them from the data? Probably at least the number of channels must be known a priori.

Comment: Also, can't you just send the base64 encoded image data, instead of passing through a csv?

Comment: The opencv format for a bgr matrix is: B,G,R,  B,G,R, ... etc. In the answer below I gave you an example of a 3x2 bgr matrix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each row of the csv file represent a line. If your image is 1 channel each value is the grayscale value for the pixel:

```
1,2,3 
4,5,6 
7,8,9
```

The resulting 3x3 1 channel image is:

[image]

If your image is 3 channel, 3 consecutive values in each line represent a *bgr* triplet. For example this:

```
1,2,3,200,100,200
4,5,6,47,205,103
7,8,9,95,23,209
```

results in a 3x2 3 channel image:

[image]

The `loadFromCSV` function accepts the string of the csv content, and the OpenCV image type, and returns the image:

```
Mat loadFromCSV(const string& values, int opencv_type);
```

Take a look at the full code:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

Mat loadFromCSV(const string& values, int opencv_type)
{
    Mat m;

    stringstream ss(values);
    string line;
    while (getline(ss, line))
    {
        vector<double> dvals;

        stringstream ssline(line);
        string val;
        while (getline(ssline, val, ','))
        {
            dvals.push_back(stod(val));
        }

        Mat mline(dvals, true);
        transpose(mline, mline);

        m.push_back(mline);
    }

    int ch = CV_MAT_CN(opencv_type);

    m = m.reshape(ch);
    m.convertTo(m, opencv_type);
    return m;
}

int main()
{
    string values = "1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9";
    Mat img = loadFromCSV(values, CV_8UC1);
    //Mat img = loadFromCSV(values, CV_8UC3);

    //string values = "1,2,3,200,100,200\n4,5,6,47,205,103\n7,8,9,95,23,209";
    //Mat img = loadFromCSV(values, CV_8UC3);

    cout << "Img:" << endl;
    cout << img << endl;

    imshow("Img", img);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like misunderstood how the BGR matrix looks like, np.array is only there so I can pipe something over to the C++ code. I will change my np.array to a correct looking BGR as you showed above, thanks for your answers, I'll get back to you after I have tried your example ;-) @Miki

Comment: Worked like a charm! :-)